# Not taking a Picture on Clicking a Button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to take picture with custom button. My `OverLayViewController` is my controller on which there is button in which perform action take picture but they not click . And  warning show on this line:

> Assigning id  nullabel from incomtable pointer OverlayViewcontroller strong imagePicker.delegate = overlay;

```
- (void)takePicture
{
    imagePicker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
    imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
    imagePicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
    imagePicker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    imagePicker.toolbarHidden = YES;
    imagePicker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;;

    OverLayViewController * overlay =[[OverLayViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"OverLayViewController" bundle:nil];

    overlay.pickerrefrence = imagePicker;
    imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = overlay.view;
    imagePicker.delegate = overlay;
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:overlay.view];

    [overlay.button addTarget:self action:@selector(takePicture) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];            
}
```

Comment: Did you adopt the UIImagePickerController delegate protocol in your class OverLayViewController?